# How to create a new Mongodb in a Docker container upon startup?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Really simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:3.2.10

#create DB directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["mongod"]
```

When I run the container I want to automatically create a DB called `"CBDB"`.  I do not want to manually run the mongo shell, want the new DB to be created automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: You are inheriting the `mongo` image, you don't need to `mkdir data/db again nor exposing the same port from the parent image.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute mongo as a daemon and write an script to be executed in an entrypoint.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

As a simple example, use this Dockerfile and entrypoint:

```
FROM mongo:3.2.10

#create DB directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

EXPOSE 27017

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

In the entrypoint, you can use the mongo as a daemon, and execute a one liner to create a database and a collection. Remember to use tail (or something like supervisord) to assure that the container does not gets stopped:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongo.log
mongo --eval "db = db.getSiblingDB('new_db'); db.createCollection('new_collection');"
tail -f /var/log/mongo.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Any pointers how to execute mongo as a daemon after mogod process has started?

Comment: I have added an example in my response, you need to start mongod process directly in daemon mode.